# Did "Old Man Logan" contradict itself in regards to Hulk mating?

Tags: old-man-logan

In "Old Man Logan", the Hulk is a villain and has an entire clan of children & grand-children. During the fight with Logan near the end, Bruce Banner says the following:

> **Bruce:** A lot of folks say that I went mad. That the radiation sickness did something to my brain. But who else was I gonna mate with besides my first cousin? Jenny She-Hulk was the only woman out there who could take the damn pace!

Later after the battle, the clan is down to three individuals - Hulk, his baby son (Bruce Jr.) and his grown grandson Billy-Bob. When Billy-Bob questions the future of the clan now, Hulk responds with:

[image]

By "women from Heff's", he's referring to the local whorehouse shown earlier in the book, which is populated by solely human women.

Don't these two statements contradict each other? **If She-Hulk was the only female who could survive mating with Hulk, how does having access to human women help?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the answer lies in your question:

> Jenny She-Hulk was the only woman out there **who could take the damn pace!**

From what I remember, the Hulk clan had dozens of children, all sired in the relatively short time (20-30 years?) since the super-villains took over the world.

For normal woman, having so many babies in such time would be very taxing, not mentioning the possibility of dying DURING the intercourse, if Bruce accidentally turned  into Hulk. But She-Hulk could "take it" since she had similar regenerative abilities as her cousin.

Now when she is gone Hulk has to use regular, human women. Yes, quite a few will die  - either during the impregnation or after giving birth (which we can assume can be dangerous) and even the lucky few won't be able to keep the She-Hulk pace in baby production rate, but hey - who cares? He can always takes another one.

Comment: 50 years, actually (as stated by Logan), but still true